# Rails redis cache connection (pool) proper usage in threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

**Disclaimer**: I really must not be Googling my question properly because this does seem like a basic question.

**Basic question**: I want to how how to proper use Rails.cache in threads when I do and do not have a connection pool. This applies to Redis, Memcache or anything else that requires a connection.

## No ConnectionPool

**I believe**: If I spawn a thread, I believe that I must manually tell the cache to reconnect to Redis or else I will receive the error `Tried to use a connection from a child process without reconnecting. You need to reconnect to Redis after forking or set :inherit_socket to true.`

1. How do I reconnect? There is no `Rails.cache.reconnect` or `Rails.cache.redis.reconnect` method. The only thing I can find is `Rails.cache.redis.disconnect!`

## With ConnectionPool

The interface to Rails.cache.redis changes because it's now an instance of `ConnectionPool` instead of an instance of `Redis`.

**I believe**: If I spawn a thread, I believe that I must call checkout a connection and then check it back in? `connection = Rails.cache.redis.checkout` and then `Rails.cache.redis.checkin(connection)`? (I think in Rails 7 they introduced `with_connection` which takes a block and does the checkout and checkin for you).

2. Is this really the kind of threading maintenance work that I have to do manually? Spawn thread, worry about my cache connection pool, end thread? Or is this handled automatically when using a connection pool? What if my connection pool is just 1 connection? The DB connection pool doesn't seem to need this, eh?

Comment: No connection pool - don't think there will be an error, your thread will wait till a connection is available https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#connection-pool-options

Comment: @JoelBlum That documentation seems to suggestion that even without using ConnectionPool, threads will wait to use the single shared connection. If that's the case then why did I see that error? It would seem impossible... (note that I never use `Rails.cache.redis` directly, only `Rails.cache.read / write`)